# VBA - Remove MultiUserEditing when button gets clicked

Tags: excel, vba

In my Workbook i have some Buttons, also the option MultiUserEditing is active. With the Buttons i add or delete some sheets, so if i click the Button the MultiUserEditing should be removed and after the work is done it should be reactivated.

I know that i can remove the MultiUserEditing with:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then
    ActiveWorkbook.ExclusiveAccess
End If
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

and activate it with:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If Not ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.FullName, accessMode:=xlShared
End If
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

But i don´t know how to write it in the "ThisWorkbook" Sheet, that it will always run when one of the buttons gets clicked?

Do i really have to add this code to each button, or is there an easier and faster way?

Comment: Wrap your code into 2 procedures like `Sub DisableMultiUser()` and `Sub EnableMultiUser()` and then just call these subs from each button.

Comment: You can call them from an active-x control or a simple formula control element using `Sub` procedures as @Pᴇʜ described.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ .. okay i understand, thanks for you help. I will use this :)